# SQL get two columns from one column

Tags: sql, t-sql, select

I have a problem. I have a table where I state_id, city_id, name and type.
Column name has all the names and type says if this name is a state or a city.
If this is a state then city_id is null and if it's a city it has state_id and city_id.
I have to select all cities as a name column and the state name that they are in as a second column.
I tried something like this:

```
SELECT
 case when type = 'state' then name end as State
 , case when type = 'city' then name end as City
  FROM table
```

But this way I get state name and city as null and then all city name with null state...

Sample data:

```
state_id, city_id, name, type
1, NULL, Arizona, state
1, 1, Phoenix, city
1, 2, Scottsdale, city
2, NULL, California, state
2, 1, Beverly Hills, city
2, 2, Oakland, city
```

And I want to get result:

```
State, City
Arizona, Phoenix
Arizona, Scottsdale
California, Beverly Hills
California, Oakland
```

Comment: Could you post some sample data and an example of how the result should look like? This would make it much easier to answer your question.

Comment: I added it to the post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the table to itself; something like:

```
Select a.Name as City, b.Name as State
from MyTable a
left join MyTable b
on a.State_Id = b.State_ID
where a.type = 'city'
and b.type = 'state'
```

Comment: Your `left join` has logically become an `inner join` because of the `where`

Comment: @Charlieface - true; if Cities without a state in the database are needed, some adjustment to the where criteria will be required.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a table that contains all states and a table that contains all cities (and the respective state id). Joining those tables then gives you the dataset you are looking for.

```
SELECT a.state, b.city
FROM (SELECT state_id, name
      FROM your_table
      WHERE type = state
      GROUP BY state_id) a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT state_id, city_id, name
      FROM your_table
      WHERE type = city
      GROUP BY city_id) b
ON a.state_id = b.state_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This query uses a single sub query :

```
SELECT (SELECT NAME FROM TEMP WHERE STATE_ID = A.STATE_ID AND CITY_ID IS NULL) State, 
NAME City 
FROM TEMP A WHERE TYPE = 'City'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 create table state_city (state_id int, city_id int, name varchar(50), type varchar(50));
 insert into state_city values(1, NULL, 'Arizona', 'state');
 insert into state_city values(1, 1, 'Phoenix', 'city');
 insert into state_city values(1, 2, 'Scottsdale', 'city');
 insert into state_city values(2, NULL, 'California', 'state');
 insert into state_city values(2, 1, 'Beverly Hills', 'city');
 insert into state_city values(2, 2, 'Oakland', 'city');
```

Query (using subquery):

```
 select (select name from state_city b  where type='state' and b.state_id=a.state_id)state, name city
 from state_city a where type='city'
```

| state | city |
| --- | --- |
| Arizona | Phoenix |
| Arizona | Scottsdale |
| California | Beverly Hills |
| California | Oakland |

Query (using join):

```
 select state.name state, city.name city
 from
 (select state_id,name
 from state_city where type='city')city
 left join
 (select state_id,name
 from state_city where type='state')state
 on city.state_id=state.state_id
```

Output:

| state | city |
| --- | --- |
| Arizona | Phoenix |
| Arizona | Scottsdale |
| California | Beverly Hills |
| California | Oakland |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ca4a1a4aa77925dee26da8d52fa64de5)*